# Hide SimpleAction from DetailVIew

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress, xaf

I have a simple action in 'myclass' and I want it to be hidden when I modify a specific property
here is an example of my code :

```
     protected override void OnActivated()
            {
                base.OnActivated();
                ObjectSpace.ObjectChanged += ObjectSpace_ObjectChanged;
            }



   void ObjectSpace_ObjectChanged(object sender, ObjectChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         if( e.PropertyName == "PropertyName")
              {
                  if (PropertyName  == "A")
                  {
                      // Hide or Desactivate my SimpleAction
                  }
                 else
                  {
                // Show or Actived my SimpleAction
                  }

            }
    }
```

how can i accomplish this task ?

Comment: Did you add an action to your business class by using the `Action` attribute: https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/112619/Task-Based-Help/Actions/How-to-Create-an-Action-Using-the-Action-Attribute ?

Comment: yes of course, but the problem is that I want my simpleaction to be invisible when the operator changes a value of property ( enum type ), when the choice 1 is selected the action is visible otherwise the simpleaction will be invisible.

Comment: Is your application XAF WinForms or Web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for such common questions you should first search the DevExpress Support Center . For example for this query https://search.devexpress.com/?q=hide%20action%20ObjectMethodActions&m=SupportCenter you can get this `Approved solution`

> As described in the How to: Create an Action Using the Action Attribute article, actions declared using the Action attribute are collected by the ObjectMethodActionsViewController controller. So, you can create a view controller, access an ObjectMethodActionsViewController instance in your view controller, and hide the required action as described in the How to: Deactivate (Hide) an Action in Code article. You can find your action in the ObjectMethodActionsViewController Actions collection by the action ID. According to the How to: Create an Action Using the Action Attribute article, your ID will be your business class name and the method name separated by a dot.